# How to create Redirect URL for an app using Google API? (OAuth client)

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I need the following information for my app to work:

1) Client ID

2) Redirect URL

Setting up the app and creating an ID + secret code was easy. But I have no idea what to put as my redirect URL. I used localhost as my URL and I was able to sign into my google account but after I signed in I received **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6APk.png)

What can I do? How do I even create a redirect URL?

Answer (score 0):

In the Developer Console [credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=) page (the one in your screenshot), add your redirect URI to the "Authorized redirect URIs" text field.

Comment: Yeah, but what is my redirect URL? I dont know what it is?

Comment: I think you said you were using localhost? So it would be something like http://localhost/oauth2callback, where "oauth2callback" is the path on which your app receives the OAuth code. You need to include the redirect URI in the original authorization request.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're supplying the correct **port** and correct **route** your server is listening on too.

For example, in the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com), the working redirect URI for me is

[image]

Your port and route all depend on your server setup (ie. look in your `index.js` if you're using Node). This working sample with port 5000 is from the example server code in the [YouTube API NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-api) readme.